# Solve transcendental equation: At $α\ll 1$, $\left|\cos x + \alpha \frac{\sin x}{x}\right| > 1$, determine the width of of the $k$-th zone at $k\gg1$.

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-methods, newton-raphson, transcendental-equations, transcendental-functions

To solve this transcendental equations approximately:

At $\alpha \ll 1$ find the positive solution of inequality:

$\left|\cos x + \alpha \frac{\sin x}{x}\right| > 1$, they are divided into series of zones numbered with the integres: $k = 0, 1, \ldots$. Determine the width of of the $k$-th zone at $k \gg 1$.

My approach: if we multiphy both sides by $x$ will we get any advantage?

I need some hints for this problem: How to procceed next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the usual trigonometric identities
$$
\cos(x)+\sin(x)\fracαx=\sqrt{1+\frac{α^2}{x^2}}\cos(x+\phi(x)),~~\phi(x)\approx -\fracαx
$$
If $x\approx k\pi$, $|k|>1$, then the width of the region around that point is approximately the distance of the roots of
$$
\cos(u)=\sqrt{1+\frac{α^2}{(k\pi)^2}}^{-1}\approx 1-\frac12\frac{α^2}{(k\pi)^2}+\frac38\frac{α^4}{(k\pi)^4}
$$
for the roots closest to $u=0$. In first order, this will be $u=\pm\fracα{k\pi}$, as $\cos(u)=1-\frac12u^2+\frac16u^4+...$, so that the width is $\frac{2α}{k\pi}$.

For $k=0,\pm1$, perhaps only for $k=0$, one would have to use another approach.

---

**condensed approach** One could condense the several approximations by using $\frac{α}{x}=\tan\phi(x)\approx\tan(\frac{α}{x})$ from the start. Then the inequality reduces to
$$
\left|\cos\left(x-\phi\right)\right|< \cos\left(\phi\right)
\iff
|x-k\pi|<\frac\pi2~\land~\cos\left(x-k\pi-\phi\right)< \cos\left(\phi\right)
$$
This now can be solved easily
$$
0<x-k\pi<2\phi(x)=2\arctan\left(\frac{α}{x}\right)
$$
where the upper bound can be approximated as above.

Comment: @ Lutz Lehmann
I didn't understand the last line properly, could pease explain in a bit details? 
"For $k=0,\pm1$, perhaps only for $k=0$, one would have to use another approach."

Comment: The approximations depend on $k\pi$ being relatively large. This works very well for $|k|>3$, and still sufficiently well for the other $k\ne 0$. Compare for instance graphically with $\cos(x-α/x)/\cos(α/x)$.

Comment: @ Lutz Lehmann I did a mistake with the conditions, please check them now. The original conditions are : α≪1, and k≫1

Comment: This changes nothing, it further ensures that $\frac{α}{kπ}$ is a small number, as required for the approximations.

Comment: @ Lutz Lehmann if $k \gg 1$, then we should not be concerned about the case $k=0$, right?

Comment: Yes, but you really do not need this, $k\ge 1$ is sufficient for $α\ll 1$ to get valid estimates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119966/discussion-between-mickey-and-lutz-lehmann).